# Cygwin starting directory using Windows Terminal

Tags: windows, cygwin, windows-terminal

The guide at
https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/master/doc/user-docs/ThirdPartyToolProfiles.md
suggests to use

```
{
    "name" : "Cygwin",
    "commandline" : "C:/Cygwin/bin/bash --login -i",
    "icon" : "C:/Cygwin/Cygwin.ico",
    "startingDirectory" : "C:/Cygwin/bin"
}
```

However, I'd like the `startingDirectory` to be `$USERPROFILE`. I have attempted various different methods to change the starting directory but they have all failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick is to use the `chere` package in Cygwin, which is used to solve the same problem.  First ensure `chere` is installed in Cygwin. Then modify the `commandline` to the following:

```
                "name": "Cygwin",
                "commandline": "c:\\cygwin\\bin\\bash.exe /bin/xhere /bin/bash",
                "startingDirectory" : "%USERPROFILE%"
```

After this, you can change `startingDirectory` to any path.

Note, for those that are annoyed by the `starting /bin/bash` that is printed after launching Cygwin using this command you can simply comment out that line in `/bin/xhere` using the following sed one-liner `sed -i -e 's|^\s*echo Starting $1;|# \0|' /bin/xhere`